# How do you watch for changes in the least significant bit?

Tags: arduino

I'm working with Arduino and am beginning to work with port registers. I love the speed increases and ability to change multiple ports at the same time. However, I don't know how to watch for a single pin changing using the port registers. (I think it can be done with [bitmath](http://www.arduino.cc/playground/Code/BitMath), but I don't even know how to start with that.)

So when I check my port register I should get something like this:

```
PINB = B000xxxxx
```

Where `x` are my pin values. Any of those pins could have changed. I want to know when just the rightmost (least significant?) bit has changed. How can I use bitmath to check that just the last one has switched from a `0` to a `1`?

Comment: `if (value & 1) { ...} else {...}`

Comment: Yes, until you want edge detection. In that case you'd need one (or two) while loops on the same condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Bitmath" is indeed the answer to the problem. In your case: `x & 0x01` will "mask" all but the lowest bit. The result can be compared to `0` or `1` at your wish.

Common idioms are:

```
x & 0x01    // get only the lowest bit
x & ~0x01   // clear only the lowest bit
x & 0xFE    // same: clear only the lowest bit
x | 0x01    // set the lowest bit (others keep their state)
```

Comment: Neat! Thanks for the examples.

Comment: The first of the "Clear" examples is the one you want to stick with.  The second example (x & 0xFE) is an 8-bit-only example -- if there are any higher bits those will be cleared as well.

Answer (score 1):

To find out if the bit has changed, you need the previous value, which you mask out as the others have said --

```
int lastValue = PINB & 0x01;
```

Then in your code you do

```
int currentValue = PINB & 0x01;
```

to get the LSB of the current pin value.

To determine if there was a change to the bit you want the "exclusive OR" (^) operator -- it is "true" if and only if the two bits are different.

```
if (lastValue ^ currentValue) {
  // Code to execute goes here

  // Now save "last" as "current" so you can detect the next change
  lastValue = currentValue;
}
```